# set css using jquery doesn't seem to work

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/FT4CQ/5/

cannot manipulate style, I think I got everything ready but it doesn't work, I test with alert() and it fired.

what is wrong here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cell").mouseover(function() {
    $('this').css('opacity','0.4');
}); 

});
```

Comment: this should not be in Single quote `this`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do this:

```
 $(this).css('opacity','0.4');
```

instead of `'this'`, see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FT4CQ/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this by removing the quotes from `this`:

```
$(this).css('opacity','0.4');
```

instead of

```
$('this').css('opacity','0.4');
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FT4CQ/9/)**

Comment: @RahulPatil:- Yes he was few seconds quicker than me and thats why he got the upvotes ;)

Answer (score 1):

Needs to be

```
$(this)
```

Instead of

```
$('this')
```

The latter would look for an HTML tag of this

Answer (score 1):

Should be using:

```
 $(this).css('opacity','0.4');
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FT4CQ/8/)**

Comment: Answered already by Manish... How if we see the previous answers before submitting a new one sir?

Comment: It was not there before i started answering it.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you are treating `this` as keyword. Hence, it does not need quotes around.

Write:

```
$(this).css('opacity','0.4');
```

instead of

```
$('this').css('opacity','0.4');
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/FT4CQ/10/)

Answer (score 1):

you are mistakenly treating this as a string by enclosing it in quotes. just remove the quotes

i have updated it as [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/FT4CQ/11/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".cell").mouseover(function() {
$(this).css('opacity','0.4'); // HERE
}); 

});
```